# When was my text message delivered?

Tags: sms, sony-xperia-x10-mini

In the text messaging application that came with my Android phone, a checkmark seems to appear next to text messages that have been successfully delivered. How can I find out when a text message was delivered?

**Update:** The text messaging app might be a custom one. It's the default for Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 mini. A couple of screen caps I've found:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the check mark is appeared on the message text body, it means it delivered the message.

If you want a confirmation then you can use [mysms SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms) app. This could deliver the status message.

If you want to track the time when the SMS delivered then try [SMS Scheduler](http://That%20is%20possible%20with%20the%20above%20given%20application.). It keeps track of all your previous messages also.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to constantly watch every message.

Comment: @Tim: You mean to say some kind of "Delivered Successfully" message back to your mobile ?

Comment: I don't want to be notified when it _is_ delivered. I want to be able to find out when it _was_ delivered, i.e. at which time the checkmark appeared.

Comment: @Tim: Please see my updated post.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way with the native application. I'll check your suggestion out.

Comment: There are many things that are not there in native Android phones. Its like a framework where we can do lots of things outside.

Answer (score 0):

In the Stock App for Short Messages, there is a way to get the informations you want to have:

Just longtap on the message and then choose "details" in the pop up.

If your manufacturer put another app for text messaging in replace for the android stock app, please tell us the name of it.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to be the stock app. Longtapping only lets me choose "Copy message text", "Forward messge" and "Delete message". I've updated the question with some more info.

Answer (score 0):

The SMS system itself doesn't support read or delivery confirmation past delivery to the network.
IOW your phone is notified when the message is received by the network with a recognised recipient, but nothing more. 
If your application is like the one on my phone, the mark indicates unread responses to a message you sent (or unread incoming messages in general), not that a message you sent has been read by its recipient.

Comment: It might mean that the message has been received by the network, but I'm quite sure that it's about a message being received by the recipient. I know that it's possible for SMS messages to request a receipt.